# make a bootstrap card clickable without affecting other links on card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let says I have this following bootstrap card

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h1>Some heading</h1>

    <a href="/link1" class="stretched-link">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/link2">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when i click on link 2 it should go to /link2 but when i click on the card elsewhere it should go to /link1

Comment: try event.preventDefalt();  Also, read about event bubbling.

Comment: so should I use event.preventDefault() on link1 or on link2

Comment: wrap the other content with the link1 anchor.
if your card has padding you should reset it and put it on the anchors.
creating a codepen would be more informative to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pseudo-element on the first link would work provided it covers the whole card which can be achieved by positioning it absolutely.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

a.stretched-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.second {
  /* required */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h1>Some heading</h1>

    <a href="/link1" class="stretched-link">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/link2" class="second">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the W3C for HTML4:

12.2.2 Nested links are illegal but you can used js to handle Nested links

```html
<div class="card" onclick="window.location='https://text.com'" style="cursor: pointer;"
  tabindex="1">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1>Some heading</h1>

        <a href="/link2">Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[here you can study more](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element)